# How to add values to many side in one to many relationship spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have merchant and address tables. one merchant can have multiple address and one address has one merchant(one to many relationship).When add merchant value with address I'm getting this error. How to solve this error?
This is the error.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1554878673504,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/merchant-service/save-merchant"
}
```

This is my input values:

```
 {
        "idNo": null,
        "idType": null,
        "emailId": "email@gmail.com",
        "name": null,
        "status": true,
        "createdBy": null,
        "modifiedBy": null,
        "createdDate": null,
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "contacts": [
            {"contactNo": "0766601122"}],
        "addresses": [
            {"line1": "manipay"},
            {"line1": "suthumalai"}
            ]
    }
```

this is my code in merchant model:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "merchant")
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(
            0);
```

this is my code in Address model:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", nullable = false)
//    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
//    @Getter(onMethod = @__( @JsonIgnore))
//    @Setter
    private Merchant merchant;
```

this is my service:

```
public Merchant saveMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
       merchant = merchantRepository.save(merchant);
       return merchant;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't posted the full stack trace of the exception, but my guess is that you have a non-null constraint on address.merchant_id, and since your code never sets address.merchant to a non-null value before inserting the merchant and its addresses, Hibernate stores null in merchant_id, thus causing the constraint violation.

Comment: @JBNizet when i add merchant at the same time i want to add the addresses to that merchant id. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Yes. Set the merchant field of the addresses: `merchant.getAddresses().forEach(address -> address.setMerchant(merchant))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Merchent table:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "merchant")
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(
            0);
```

In Address table:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
        @Getter(onMethod = @__( @JsonIgnore))
        @Setter
        private Merchant merchant;
```

In Service:

```
public Merchant saveMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
       merchant = merchantRepository.save(merchant);
        Merchant finalMerchant = merchant;
        merchant.getAddresses().forEach(address -> {
           address.setMerchant(finalMerchant);
           addressRepository.save(address);
       });
       return merchant;
    }
```

It is perfectly working.

Comment: You shouldn't create a new merchant for each address. You should set the unique merchant in each address.

Comment: @JBNizet Here I'm doing like that.

Comment: I'm giving one merchant id to all address.

Comment: All addresses are supposed to have the same merchant. So why do you create a **new** merchant for every address. Just set the same merchant object on every address.

Comment: That is empty merchant object and after adding merchant i'm getting that id and set the id to merchant object and attached to address.setMerchant. It is working for me. if you have any doubt i will send my out put.

Comment: first i'm adding merchant then i'm using that id to every address creation.

Comment: It's working, but it's needlessly complicated and inefficient, and wrong, since, I repeat, all the addresses should have **the same** merchant: the one that you save at the start of the method.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated that answer please can you check it?

Comment: It's much better. You could make it even simpler by setting the merchant on addresses before saving the merchant, and by removing the call to addressRepository.save(address), since you have a cascade, and saving the merchant would thus save the addresses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191650/discussion-between-majutharan-majutharan-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1):

I your Merchant model, you set `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` for the addresses attribute. That means for this case if you want to persist a Merchant object with some addresses, the **hibernate** will check if these addresse already exist; if not it will create them before. But in your Address model, you set `nullabel = false` to merchant attribute that means Address object can't be persist without existing Merchant. Then when the **hibernate** try to persist Merchant and find Address that is not yet persisted, it try to persist this Address before, it also find a null Merchant object then throw this exception `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`.

You have to choose one of these proposals:

- Remove `nullable = false` constraint in merchant attribute on Address model. if you do that, Address will be persisted without Merchant. Then when you persist Merchant **hibernate** will update Address.
- Change `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` to all other cascade except PERSIST in addresses attribute of Merchant model. If you do that, you should persist Merchant before yourself then persist Address with existing Merchant.

Comment: Can you change in my code because i couldn't understand your answer.

Comment: Try this @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id") instead of @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", nullable = false)

Comment: {
    "timestamp": 1554885216731,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/merchant-service/save-merchant"
}

Comment: in spring boot log : java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'merchant_id' cannot be null

Comment: I am sure that in the address table the merchant_id field has not null constraint. You have to also remove it .

Comment: I have solved that problem. I have added that answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It says you have a Constraint violation  error, which means you might have set any one of the variable in the entity to be not null, and you are trying to save a null value.

Comment: here merchant id not set. I know that point but my scenario when add  merchant  at the same time addresses want to add in address table with merchant id.

Comment: why dont you get the addresses first, save them in the address table and then, use `merchant.getAddresses.set(addresses)`